How to setup coturn configuration with nginx reverse proxy

I have network architecture, as shown in the image below. I need to set up coturn configuration to enable the UDP port with the firewall corporate network. This network has blocked UDP ports and opens only 80/TCP and 443/TCP. I need to set up webRTC with Jitsi with 10000/UDP ports. So May I get to know how to set up the TURN server and STUN server configuration for this network?  I tried this on the proxy server configuration but when testing it failed with the below output. 
Configuration as this setup.
server-name=xxx.meet.io
realm=xxx.meet.io
cert=/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.meet.io/cert.pem
pkey=/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.meet.io/privkey.pem
fingerprint
listening-ip=0.0.0.0
external-ip=a.a.a.a/c.c.c.c #or just the external ip
listening-port=443
min-port=10000
max-port=20000
log-file=/var/log/turnserver.log
verbose

static-auth-secret=<YOUR_SECRET>


no chance configuring the firewall so that udp ports are not blocked?

No this is unable because corporate rules
